# PLL (Phase Locked Loop)

Tags: signal, oscillator, frequency, oscillation, multiplier

I find a bit of confusion on the web about the use of the PLL. Sometimes I read that, given a certain input signal, it is used to generate a signal whose frequency is N times that od the input one, when N is chosen by us.

If we look at the following image, the previous statement means that the difference between the phases of the signals that enter the phase detector is constant in time.

Sometimes I read that a PLL allows to get that the input signals of the phase detector have the same phase, that means that their phase difference is 0 (so it is a stricter condition).

What does the PLL exactly do?
[image]

Comment: think of this ... you have a light that blinks briefly every 5 seconds ... just for fun, you want to count the seconds ... start count when the light blinks .... count at approximate 1 second intervals ... 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 .... if you get to "one" before the light blinks, you slow down your count .... if you do not get to "one", you speed up your count ..... when your counting is synchronized with the light, then you are counting exactly 5 times faster than the light

Comment: Think...beginner music student trying to count the sub-beats in their head in between metronome beats and constantly adjustting their count so it falls onto the metronome beat.

Comment: A simple XOR phase detector with inputs shifted 90 deg = Vdd/2 is one locked condition. http://tinyurl.com/y6pmbw4l   There are others.

Comment: Think of the beat frequency of tuning a guitar as the filtered phase detector output controlling VCO to go up or down

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A PLL locks the phase error to zero.  This is the base concept of a PLL.

A PLL that has a divide-by-N in its feedback path locks the phase error to zero, and as a result it generates a frequency N times higher than its reference frequency -- then it is called a "frequency synthesizer".

A PLL that detects the difference in timing between its oscillator and the bits in a bitstream is called a "bit timing recovery loop"

A PLL that detects the difference in timing between its oscillator and the carrier of a digital signal is called a "carrier recovery loop".

There are all sorts of ways to use the PLL concept, and sometimes authors just call the result a "PLL" -- so you need to pay attention!

Comment: At least in my area, the 2nd one is most often called a "clock [from] data recovery" (CDR) circuit.

Comment: I've seen bit clock recovery and data clock recovery, too.